# "chmod --reference=<reference file> <file>" returns "chmod: illegal option -- -" on macOS

Tags: chmod, macos

I'm learning how to change the permissions on files.  On my macOS system, I want to copy the permissions from one file to another using the `chmod --reference=reference-file file` command, however it keeps returning

```
chmod: illegal option -- -
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `chmod` on macOS is not GNU `chmod` (which is usually found on Linux systems), and does not therefore support the special non-standard GNU "long options".

On macOS, you may still get access to GNU `chmod` via the Homebrew package manager.  The utility is available as `gchmod` once you install the `coreutils` package with

```
brew install coreutils
```

Answer (score 4):

If your version of `chmod` doesn't support `--reference` and you don't want to install additional software, you can use `stat` to get the reference file's permissions, and use that. Unfortunately, `stat` itself is hopelessly inconsistent between different OSes/versions. On macOS (and NetBSD and probably other BSDs), you'd use:

```
chmod "$(stat -f "%Mp%Lp" referencefile)" file
```

While if you had the GNU version of `stat` (and for some reason didn't have the GNU version of `chmod`), it'd be:

```
chmod "$(stat -c "%a" referencefile)" file
```

On other OSes... check `man 1 stat` and see what the local dialect is.